# Using foreach to iterate through an array within an array (returns double entries)

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have the following code:

```
echo "Size of array: " . sizeof($userDetails) . $this->newline;
foreach($userDetails as $i) {
    echo "Item: " . $i . $this->newline;
}
```

... when I run it, I get

Size of array: 1
Item: Array

To try and display the array, I changed it to:

```
echo "Size of array: " . sizeof($userDetails) . $this->newline;
foreach($userDetails as $a) {
    foreach($a as $i) {
    echo "Item: " . $i . $this->newline;
    }
}
```

This seems to work, and I get the following output:

```
Size of array: 1

Item: Graham

Item: Graham

Item: XYZ

Item: XYZ

Item: 180337955-yu29UNDy8idaryz9ilkXCVTo7Osjus76RWEud5ZU

Item: 180337955-yu29UNDy8idaryz9ilkXCVTo7Osjus76RWEud5ZU

Item: HyMkKJWISYHSLSSHS89261702id54Fjr7uKSUS8yo

Item: HyMkKJWISYHSLSSHS89261702id54Fjr7uKSUS8yo

Item: PihJSISJ8MgpkJS8S7xgyA

Item: PihJSISJ8MgpkJS8S7xgyA

Item: JS87SGSKSHJJSLKIUKJjhsllsjkjskjkjlEDTxyQ

Item: JS87SGSKSHJJSLKIUKJjhsllsjkjskjkjlEDTxyQ

Item: pid.bjk

Item: pid.bjk
```

You'll see that each item (which is correctly displayed) is repeated (it should not be). This suggests that I am  using foreach wrong.

Can anybody tell me how I shoudl be using foreach correctly?

Thank you in advance.

G

Comment: show us the output of `var_dump($userDetails);`

Comment: [deleted comment]

Comment: looks like you are retrieving the results from mysql using mysql_fetch_array. This will give you double values because it includes result as a combination of associative array and normal array. try using mysql_fetch_assoc. That should give you only one set of values.

Comment: Ahhh

array(1) { [0]=> array(14) { [0]=> string(14) "Graham" ["username"]=> string(14) "Graham" [1]=> string(3) "XYZ" ["databaseTable"]=> string(3) "XYZ"  etc........ Size of array (a): 14

Each entry is duplicated. Once with a key of 'count' and once with a key of 'name'.

I have no idea why that is happening - and if that is usual?

[Thx for quick response]

Comment: Yes - it is an SQL query. It is not my code - but I have access to it. I will try as you suggest - thank you.

Comment: Edit your question and add the output there instead

Comment: Using mysql_fetch_assoc worked, thank you

Comment: [Not sure how to edit question]